# Belonging as a virtue

Tags: practical-ethics

I'm interested in any values that stand up without being grounded in God or immortality; but which are achievable potentials.

Does anyone in (analytic or not) philosophy claim that there is an ethic of **belonging**?

By "belonging" I mean a way of behaving which essentially includes being *understood*; being understood to the extent that the rest of the group agrees, or can show you how you are wrong this time.

> When at last the Buddha came to his follower Mahakasyapa, the disciple
>   suddenly understood. He smiled and began to laugh. Buddha handed the
>   lotus to Mahakasyapa

An antecedent (of sorts) of my question in the [Flower Sermon](http://www.katinkahesselink.net/tibet/flower-sermon.htm).

Comment: I have difficulties (I am not a native speaker): What do you mean by *to align a value to belonging?* And how  is belonging related to *to speak and to be understood*? Could you please add some more explication, thank you.

Comment: @jowehler any clearer ?

Comment: i googled it and mostly uninspiring stuff about nursing hah :)

Comment: Yes, it's better. But do you mean simply "understandable communication and behaving according to the social rules"?

Comment: There's the Frankfurt School notion of deliberative democracy.

Comment: And communicative rationality.

Comment: @MoziburUllah yeah i had a go at answering along those lines, below :)

Comment: There's also an anecdote from Confucious that comes to mind.

Comment: An ethic/virtue, or a value?  Maslow and others in his psychological vein have suggested a need for belonging, making it a thing of value which is to be handled in any appropriate ethics.  But that is kind of the flip-side of an 'ethic' of belonging.  After all, there is are values about food, but no 'ethic of food'.

Comment: There is something called *communitarianism*, whose name suggests an alignment with your question; but I know little about it; it may be a modern take on virtue ethics.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a valid argument for "belonging," but it was explicitly opposed to the concept of being a thing which was actually "achievable."

The pattern worked like this.  If we start from the presumption that we are imperfect, and that we must interpret any ethics using our imperfect self, then it is potentially possible to misinterpret any perfect ethical rule.  Many systems claim the result of this misinterpretation to be suffering.  However, if we work as a group, we can be collectively more sensitive to the minute details around us, and are more likely to collectively achieve an interpretation of the ethics which is better than an individual can.

If one finds a group which seeks such goals, then "belonging" has ethical merit.  If one belongs, by your words, the group understands you.  That means that there is a group (which you presumably trust) which can turn that sensitivity onto you, and help you identify that within yourself which you "should" change.

I have also found there to be a biological defense of such an argument: the way our cells grow and are taught how to behave follows a similar pattern.  The whole of the body knows more about the world than, say, an individual muscle fiber, and can work with that fiber to teach it the exact best way to contract and relax to accomplish goals that are much too subtle for a mere muscle fiber to have fully comprehended on its own.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in any values that stand up without being grounded in
>   God or immortality; but which are achievable potentials.

Given my tentative solution, perhaps what is troubling me is an inability to claim what everyone involved would agree with it - knowing full well all of its consequences. This is something *like* the "rightness" of Habermas, which makes an ethical claim "universal"

> All affected can accept the consequences and the side effects that
>   [the norm's] general observance can be anticipated to have for the
>   satisfaction of everyone's interests, and the consequences are
>   preferred to those of known alternative possibilities for regulation

One thing that makes this more attractive than Kant's universal, is that it does not assume it is made true by

> a relation to reality (inner or outer)

Janna Thompson 1998 p32. They also note that this

> is not undermined by a failure of individuals to reach agreement

---

One thing that could make my above ethic is "communicative competence":

> The immediate and manifest aim of communicative competence is
>   understanding and consensus... [and it] anticipates the "ideal speech situation"...  in which "there is no other compulsion but the compulsion of argumentation itself"

Heydebrand and Burris 1984 p407. Of course, Habermas is famous for rubbishing a lot of his work based on the claim that the ideal speech situation is **unachievable**.

So if there is (regardless) a speech community in which "communicative competence" can achieve "rightness", then my "belonging" is valuable if *within this community* all prefer to participate in it than not. So far I hope to have clarified the question.

---

### An attempt at an answer

Can any community establish "rightness" as actual agreement? And what would make participation in that community preferable?

1. I would *suggest* that the former is enough to make the latter manifest: with any actual consensus everyone agrees there is a consensus; so everyone involved wants to be a part of that consensus.
2. And **suggest** that agreement can create an ethic of sorts, as long as everyone in agreement is equally able to live according to it.

So the value of "belonging" amounts to a community in which everyone is equally able to reach consensus about what is preferable. As such I suppose that beyond an "ideal speech situation", *a community of interests* would also satisfy me. Whether or not it is an absolute good

Comment: As I understand this answer reviews the original question. In addition, you answer your own question, which is OK. Unfortunately, the logical structure of the present question and answer remains unclear to me. - If I consider only some of your key concepts I associate 1) Habermas discourse ethics. Probably alike the comment of @Mozibur 2) *Rawls: A Theory of Justice*. I consider the latter a seminal paper from political philosophy.

Comment: not sure what you think i must change ?

Comment: I'm confused by the use of "you" and the use of quoting when answering a question you yourself asked. / p.s., there's quite a few interesting solutions outside of this where relationality is a virtue.

Comment: @virmaior i'll leave it with "you" unless anyone else chimes in; i think it makes it easier to read? i concluded that having shared interests is good, though not absolute; who agrees ?

Comment: I found the use of 'you' confusing too when you're answering your own question; as a matter of 'communicative rationality' is there not some other natural possibility?